# IDEA: how to handle "Module 'A' sources do not depend on module 'B' sources" warning

Tags: intellij-idea, dependencies, code-inspection

How can I tell ignore IDEA to ignore this warning permanently?

```
Module 'A' sources do not depend on module 'B' sources
```

Note:

- Basically the warning is correct, because A does not use any source code of B
- But B contains some annotation processor logic, that is required when compiling A
- Thus, B declares a dependency on A (I use maven and the scope is set to `provided` - which works just fine)
- In the `Inspection Results` dialogue I can select 'Exclude' - but this is not permanent: i.e. when I start Analyze again, the warning will reappear
- I also do not want to disable the notification for everything

The only workaround, that I found, is to really add a reference to the code of A (e.g. in a simple fake test method) - but I hope there is maybe a better way.